# Mysql fixing root password

Tags: mac-osx

I guess I messed up the `user` table trying to update the password running something like

```
UPDATE mysql.user SET authentication_string='root' WHERE User='root';
```

without flushing privileges. Now I'm basically locked out and I cannot connect to mysql cli even if I try

```
sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables &
```

There is a way I can **safely** remove all mysql databases including `user` table?

(MacOS mojave)

This is the content of `/usr/local/bin` related to `mysql`

```
mysql               mysqladmin          mysqlpump
mysql.server            mysqlbinlog         mysqlrouter
mysql_client_test       mysqlcheck          mysqlrouter_plugin_info
mysql_config            mysqld              mysqlshow
mysql_config_editor     mysqld_multi            mysqlslap
mysql_secure_installation   mysqld_safe         mysqltest
mysql_ssl_rsa_setup     mysqldump           mysqlxtest
mysql_tzinfo_to_sql     mysqldumpslow
mysql_upgrade           mysqlimport
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the problem, basically almost all the solution you can find around are **outdated**.
With mysql 8.0.15 you have to follow this guide
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/resetting-permissions.html

Using the method `UPDATE mysql.user SET authentication_string..` ***will lock you out from your own mysql server*** (you won't solve even with `mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables`).

Answer (score 2):

First backup your `/etc/mysql` and `/var/lib/mysql` directories.

Then try to initalize

```
mysql_install_db
```

to recreate the mysql schema from scratch.

You can read about it here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql-install-db.html

Comment: I do not have both those dirs. And I get `command not found` launching `mysql_install_db`. It is a fresh installation I don't have any db I have to save. I don't mind wiping up the whole mysql installation. But I'm not clear what to do other than uninstall using `brew`

Comment: what `whereis mysql` says?

Comment: `which mysql` prints `/usr/local/bin/mysql` (`whereis` prints nothing)

Comment: Ah, my mistake, I have confused OS. Look for mysql configuration, binaries and files somewhere inside /usr/local, you may try to use `locate mysql` for this job.

Comment: I edited the question with my mysql bins in `/usr/local/bin` if it helps

Answer (score 1):

You could simply uninstall mysql and purge configuration files if you don't need the databases or any settings.

The steps would be:

```
brew uninstall mysql
brew cleanup
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/var/mysql    ## verify within my.cnf
```

**ps. Take this with a grain of salt, as I'm not a MacOS user.**

Comment: I would avoid mess up the whole sistem, I will search around a little bit. macOS it's a f nightmare...

Comment: ok even removing `/usr/local/var/mysql` didn't solved..

Comment: You might need to remove the binaries too, try this also: `sudo rm -rf /usr/local/bin/mysql`.